# How to install pear HTTP_Client on windows?

Tags: pear

When am following [this](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.installing.php) am getting error pear is not recognized & it is not internal or external command.
So please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: So you didn't click though to http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php and try installing it by following the deatils there? Also you haven't mentioned what operating system you're using so nobody can give specific details on how to install on whatever it is you're using.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download this script http://pear.php.net/go-pear
2. save it to your webserver directory
3. Rename it to go-pear.php
4. Run it from your favorite browser to install

This is installation wizard so you will be asked some information to fill in. Leave most of them as is and click on next to install.